# Is selection in Taligent MVP assumed to be a Selection Model?

Tags: mvp

By reading the [traditional Taligent paper](http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf), I can't find a definite answer to what they mean by Selection. The selection could be just a set of indices referring to entries in the Model, so that a Command can act on the proper Model subset, but what is not clear from the Paper is how they represent this selection in the View.

There are two possibilities to this:

- either they assumed that all visual selection representation is handled by the View, and the selection they talk about is nothing but a "set of indices" object that is extracted from the View by the Presenter and fed to the Command.
- or the selection is an actual Selection Model, and as such must be made available to the View so that it can inquire about it for visual representation (e.g. a User action "Select all" modifies the Selection Model, which notifies the View to highlight all the items). However, from the paper, this connection between the selection and the View is not present.

How is Taligent MVP formally supposed to handle a Selection's visual presentation?